# Spark 2.2.0 - How to list files in S3 bucket from EC2

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I want to load files based on the timestamp present in their file name. These files are in a S3 bucket. When I run my script locally, reading from a local folder, it works without issue. When I run it on EC2 trying to access my S3 bucket, the `java.io.File.listFiles` returns an empty array.

What am I missing?

```
import main.scala.util.Util._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.Seq
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType



object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val path = "s3://my-bucket/subbucket/"

    val now: String = extractDate("2017-01-12").toString

    var files = new java.io.File(path)
           .listFiles
           .filter(p => date_filter(p,now))
           .map(path+_.getName)
           .toSeq

    val df = spark.read.csv(files:_*)

    df.show()

  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not a dupe of those. It's really "how can I read in CSV files from S3 in spark" .  Try . spark.read.csv("s3://my-bucket/subbucket/2017-01-12/") and have it do the listing and scheduling of work across files